# Where can I find the missing dependencies for git-svn for redhat 7

Tags: git, svn, redhat, yum

I am trying to install git-svn on redhat 7.2 but the yum install fails with some missing dependencies.

```
Error: Package: git222-perl-Git-SVN-2.22.3-1.el7.ius.noarch (ius)
       Requires: perl(SVN::Ra)
Error: Package: git222-perl-Git-SVN-2.22.3-1.el7.ius.noarch (ius)
       Requires: perl(SVN::Delta)
Error: Package: git222-perl-Git-SVN-2.22.3-1.el7.ius.noarch (ius)
       Requires: perl(SVN::Core)

yum provides SVN:Core

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager   
epel/x86_64/filelists_db    
rhel-7-workstation-rpms/7Workstation/x86_64/filelists_db  
slack/filelists                 
No matches found
```

I found a few pages on installing svn-git that recommend creating a repository, but I am getting 404's on the URLs when I try to use them. I had a similar problem with git 2.x that I got around by building from a tarball.I have not been able to find a git-svn tarball. Can someone provide a sample repository that will resolve those dependencies?

Comment: Looks like you also need the IUS repo [Here](https://repo.ius.io/ius-7.repo) let me know if that fixes your issue.

Comment: no luck, I get the same errors. I tried both using a separate .repo file and adding the repos to the epel.repo.  I've worked around the problem by installing a cent-os 8 virtual machine. That seems to have no issues with the install.

Comment: did you remember to check/set `enabled=yes` in the `.repo` file? Also it looks like those deps come from [subversion-perl-1.7.14-6.el7](ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/matthewdva:/build:/RedHat:/RHEL-7/optional/x86_64/subversion-perl-1.7.14-6.el7.x86_64.rpm) which can be found in the base repo `base/7/x86_64`

Comment: enabled=1. I tried installing the linked version of subversion-perl, but itis incompatible with the version of subversion that yum has installed. Package subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
 rpm -ivf subversion-perl-1.7.14-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
 subversion(x86-64) = 1.7.14-6.el7 is needed by subversion-perl-1.7.14-6.el7.x86_64.  A yum install of subversion-perl yields 'no package found'.  I was able to get my code  base moved to git using a centos machine with a 2.x version of git installed on it (from wandisco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to install git-svn on redhat 7.2

RHEL 7.2 was released 2015-11-19, almost five years ago.  IUS packages are built against the current released version, which is currently 7.8.  On a current system, those perl dependencies are provided by the subversion-perl package from the base repository.

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo)
# repoquery --whatprovides 'perl(SVN::Core)' | sort -V | tail -1
subversion-perl-0:1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64
```

Fully updating your system will allow git222-svn to be installed.